# Сертификат SSL от godaddy не работает на поддомене

Tags: ssl

Привет всем. Я купил сертификат безопасности SSL для домена example.com и он работает с доменном example.com с ним нет никаких проблем нет, но когда я пытаюсь использовать его для поддомена forum.example.com браузер пишет что он недействителен 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер пишет следующее при попытке открыть сайт: сертификат действителен только для следующих имён: example.com, www.example.com

Тип сертификата Standard SSL [prntscr.com/9dbuk4](http://prntscr.com/9dbuk4)

Тут написано https://uk.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate что Standard SSL должен работать с поддоменами, странно что не работает.

Вопрос простой почему, и как это исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 4):

А должен?

Мы для таких вещей покупаем Wildcard SSL сертификат, он работает на все поддомены. Если мне память не изменяет, то обычный сертификат не работает с поддоменами. Иногда при покупке сертификата предоставляют возможность вбить 2-3 поддомена, на которые так же должен распространяться сертификат.

Если вы уже купили сертификат на один домен и ничего дополнительного не указывали, то вряд ли получится его настроит на субдомен.

Answer (score 2):

вам нужно предоставить больше информации. как устанавливали, какие конфиги. так же есть разные виды сертификатов.wildcard вроде поддерживает поддомены, какой приобретен у вас?

Comment: спасибо кто добавил. теперь хватает

Comment: Пож. Вот что пишет godaddy Encryption Strength GoDaddy SHA-2
Validity Period 9/12/2015 - 5/12/2016
Serial Number 9e:bc:bf:55:05:da:ba:5f

Comment: по этой информации я не могу понять какой у вас сертификат. для поиска ответа, предлагаю вам зайти на godaddy
https://ru.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate
и посмотреть, какой сертификат вы выбрали, и поддерживает ли он поддомены.

https://gyazo.com/b367e08f66d537d273c07e4f77658034

Comment: Standard SSL http://prntscr.com/9dbuk4

Comment: Тут написано https://uk.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate что Standard SSL должен работать, странно что не работает.

Comment: @dimaua вы брали UCC/SAN SSL?

Comment: @dimaua самый дешёвый сертификат "Secures one website"

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6116b662b1f894b752b2f9624192c4ad
Single Domain.
Single = Один.
Кажется ваш сертификат не поддерживает поддомены